# How to compare current time to retrieve record stored in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a database in which one of the column name is 'date' I need to count the number of entries that have been added with today's date after 09.00.00

So far I have done this..I am wondering where do I specify the time '09.00.00'

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS  total from DATABASENAME
WHERE date  >= Convert(datetime, Convert(int, GetDate()))
```

Comment: In SQL server 2012 it gets todays date and time, im not too sure though I used a online soloution

Comment: OK.  What does `GetDate()` do then?

Comment: GetDate() gets todays date and time

Comment: It is stored as YYYY/MM/DD and I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: So `datetime` gets today's date and time, and `GetDate()` gets todays' date and time?  I'm confused.

Comment: Is it possible to get the correct way of doing this please?

Comment: I'm not sure we can.  You haven't given us enough to work with.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am not sure if this is correct way to do it as I got this query from the net can you please correct it? It will be much appreciated!

Comment: `Stored as YYYY/MM/DD` is that a `CHAR(10)` or do you mean it is in a `DATE` column, and that is the format you see when you do a query - do you see the difference? You really need a `DATETIME2` column if you want to check the time portion of the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's code that should work.  You're essentially converting a datetime to a date to remove the time, then back to a datetime and adding in the hour that you want.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM TableName
WHERE Date >= DATEADD(HOUR, 9, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well is the date column store date and time or date only, if it is date only you need to add the time also in the column and also avoid converting data type in where condition try the above query with a parameter variable